# How do I change my keyboard layout on linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

How do I reconfigure my keyboard layout on Linux, so that:

1. Caps lock becomes a modifier key for a numeric keyboard layout on the place of `M<>JKLUION`.
2. `;` becomes a dead key so pressing it followed by another key produces an arbitrary symbol I'm going to define.
3. A few specific keys are remapped (such as `1 !` is inverted and becomes `! 1`, for example).

**What I've tried.**

I've spent the whole day trying to configure the keyboard layout on NixOS. I've read the whole man page on "setxkbmap", and more than three huge tutorials on the internet, including [this one](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html), [this one](http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/), [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg). Some of those guides are not only incomplete, but clearly expect knowledge on things that aren't on the guide and aren't obvious at all. For example (from xmodmap's man):

```
-display This option specifies the host and display to use.
```

It doesn't in any moment define what "display" is. Or, on [this](http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/) tutorial:

> To approach these two tasks, let's create a symbols file in ~/.xkb/symbols/xkbtest and add two stanzas to it:

Which proceeds to quote a snippet with a syntax completely foreign and unexplained. Those are just 2 of a ton of missing information pieces.

I then decided to do it the hacker way. I copied a XKB file, `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols/us` to my home folder and open it with VIM. The problem is that it is a **1500+ lines long file** with tons of different keyboard layouts and syntaxes/symbols that aren't obvious regarding what they do. I don't even know what is active there.

I have tried xmodmap but, as stated, the man pages do not explain how to do what I need, nor the tutorials I looked.

I don't understand why this has to be so difficult. On both **OSX and Windows** I solved the issue in minutes with UI-keyboard editors such as **Ukelele**.

Comment: What windowing system are you using? Many windowing systems have an easy to use graphical tool to help you. If not then you have to edit some files. (Linux is just the kernel).